# Header in Latex article

Tags: header-footer

I am writing an article in latex. I would like to put the journal's name
on the header of the first page, and title of the article on the odd pages, authors name on even pages of the rest. I am trying with pagestyle{ fancy} but have failed to customize this way. Can anybody help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using? You should post at least a framework of what you've done. Can you do that?

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the headers that you want for the first page and even and odd pages.

```
% hdrprob.tex  SE 575772
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[CO]{Article title}
\fancyhead[CE]{The Authors}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{THE JOURNAL}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```